# Is it possible to access the object delegated by in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The `meow` method is delegated to the Cat. Is it possible to access the Person?

```
class Person
  attr_reader :cat

  delegate :meow, to: :cat

  def initialize
    @cat = Cat.new
  end
end

class Cat
  def meow
    # How to access Person who called meow?
  end
end


Person.new.meow
```

Comment: So many question, but let's start with an obvious one: why would a Person meow?

Comment: That's the whole point. The Person delegates to the Cat.

Comment: This seems like a massive Interface Separation Principle violation meaning that delegation is a completely wrong pattern for your scenario. Person should not respond to `meow` message, regardless of whether it is delgated or not. Unless of course, you are looking to the answer for a more generic, abstract question and Person/Cat combo is just a (wrong) example? Also - I completely missed the `k` next to your reputation, which makes the assumption of the abstract problem more likely :)

Comment: I guess you are right...the design of the example is not good...but I hope at least it makes the question clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BroiSatse already said, the example doesn't really make sense. However, you could e.g. pass in the person to the Cat.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :cat

  delegate :meow, to: :cat

  def initialize
    @cat = Cat.new(self)
  end
end

class Cat
  def initialize(owner)
    @owner = owner
  end

  def meow
    puts "#{@owner} - meow"
  end
end


Person.new.meow
```

### Edit

Another approach could be to use `SimpleDelegator` instead.

```rb
class User
  def born_on
    Date.new(1989, 9, 10)
  end
end

class UserDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def birth_year
    born_on.year
  end
end
```

And then you can access the receiver with `super` or `__getobj__()`

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html

Comment: Yes, I came up with this too...I was hoping there was a more elegant way...

Comment: What do you think is not elegant on this approach?

Comment: Answering your question with respect to the first answer, it seems strange to pass in `self`. I don't think I have ever had to do that before...makes me think something is not right...

Comment: I don't think it's strange, Arel (the Rails SQL builder) does it for instance a lot (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/arel/math.rb#L6). I think the problem is the constructed example where the person does not really make sense to be an attribute of a cat.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not really possible, or at least not in a way it is requested. Haing an access to an object invoking a method would create an absolutely fascinating type of coupling where receiver is coupled to the the caller.

That being said, there are some ways to get around this. As @ChristianBruckMayes already answered, your `Cat` class could accept extra `owner`. But this might not work, if the generic concept of Cat is quite owner-less or when one `Cat` might be an attribute of multiple `Person`.

One common pattern I use is a inner proxy object:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :cat

  delegate :meow, to: :cat

  def initialize(cat = Cat.new)
    @cat = OwnedCat.new(cat, owner: self)
  end

  class OwnedCat
    def initialize(cat, owner:)
      @cat = cat
      @owner = owner
    end

    def meow
      # access to cat and owner here
    end

    # delegate everything else to cat object
    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      return super unless @cat.respond_to?(name)
      @cat.send(name, *args, &block)
    end

    def respond_to_missing?(name, private = false)
      @cat.respond_to?(name, private)
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could just pass `self` to the method invcation:

```
class Cat
  def meow(owner: nil)
    if owner
       ...
    else
       ...
    end
  end
end

def Person
  def initialize
    @cat = Cat.new
  end

  def meow
    @cat.meow(owner: self)
  end
end
```

Comment: The inner proxy object is a nice solution. I would probably use a simple delegator for it though if you anyway forward everything to cat.

Answer (score 0):

my solution: i create a module that will override `delegate` method and add some code that will setup `cat.delegator` to the caller `person` each time he delegate `meo` to his `cat`

```rb
module ForFunDelegator
  def delegate(*methods, to: nil, prefix: nil, allow_nil: nil)
    super

    location = caller_locations(1, 1).first
    file, line = location.path, location.lineno
    methods.map do |method|
      definition = /[^\]]=$/.match?(method) ? "arg" : "*args, &block"
      method_def = [
        "alias old_delegate_#{method} #{method}",
        "def #{method}(#{definition})",
        "def #{to}.delegator=(delegator)",
        "@delegator = delegator",
        "end",
        "def #{to}.delegator",
        "@delegator",
        "end",
        "#{to}.delegator = self",
        "old_delegate_#{method}(#{definition})",
        "end"
      ].join ";"
      module_eval(method_def, file, line)
    end
  end
end
```

demo

```rb
class Person
  extend ForFunDelegator

  attr_reader :cat
  delegate :meow, to: :cat

  def initialize
    @cat = Cat.new
  end
end

class Cat
  def meow
    puts delegator if respond_to?(:delegator) # Person:0x00007fa158868098
  end
end

Person.new.meow
```

now the `Cat` or anything else no need to concern about the `self` which is the delegator, the delegator module will do on behalf of them.